# change position of img dynamically to mouse position via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm trying to change the position of a `img` dynamically to my mouse position on every click via jquery. The problem is that it doesn't work. And i mean it doesn't move at all. Here's my jquery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
    $('#circle').css({position:'absolute', 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY});
    });
});
```

Help would be appreciated. I'm kinda new to this so, ill need you to guide me through your answers a bit. Thanks in advance.

Here's my html and css code as requested:

```
#circle {
    max-width:25px;
    max-height:36px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #ffffff);
}
```

HTML: (Inside my body tag)

```
<img src="Images/circleIcon.png" id="circle">

<div id="JavaScript_JQuery">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jUI.js"></script>
</div>
```

Ok it's working now.. But i have another problem. The image is duplicating itself with every click. Why do you think that's happening? And how to solve it?

Comment: It would be helpful to also see your HTML markup. Thanks.

Comment: do you have a closest parent with `position:relative`?

Comment: Works great for me http://jsfiddle.net/5ZJLT/

Comment: I'm betting it occurs because the code you have is being run on document ready (when the img is not on the page). You should try running it once the img has loaded or re-running it then

Comment: @Zeaklous. I clicked run again and it didn't work the second time

Comment: If you're talking about your project, you can't simply refresh the page. You must run the code on the page where the image has shown up, like as a callback function after dynamically adding it. If you're talking about my jsfiddle, it should work all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the circle position on every click:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        var radius = $('#circle').height() / 2;
        $('#circle').css({'left':e.pageX - radius, 'top':e.pageY - radius});
    });    
});
```

See the live example:
<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUa8y/3/)**</kbd>

The problem with the duplication seems to come from `-webkit-drop-shadow`. It's just a ill-rendering.

Comment: <kbd>with those tags, doesn't work in comments, though ;) </kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your `<script>` tags should be in the `<head>` section, not in a div in the page body. You also need to make sure they are actually loading using a console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',(function(e) {
         var radius = $('#circle').height() / 2;
         $('#circle').css({position:'absolute', 'left':e.pageX-radius, 'top':e.pageY-radius});
    });
});
```

.... if you want the **CENTER** of the circle to follow the mouse click.